# Is it possible to know how many terms a geometric progression has to a certain number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I want to know how many values the $x$ takes so that the sum total $(0.5) ^ x * 0.5$ equals $1$.

But since the ratio is $0.5$, each term is less than the previous one, and the progression is approaching $0$ as the number of its terms increases.

That means that at some point the sum gives 1, but I will never know at what $ x $ value will that happen?

Comment: You mean the equation $0.5\cdot \sum_{x=0}^C 0.5^x=1$ ? And you want to find $C$ ?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I mean.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it.

Comment: You can ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closed formula for the partial sum  $$S_n=\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} r^x$$ is

$S_n=r\cdot \frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$

Thus $$0.5\cdot \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} 0.5^x=0.5\cdot \frac{1-0.5^n}{1-0.5}$$

$=1-0.5^n$

For what value of $n$ is the expression above equal to one ?

Comment: None? So the sum tends to 1 but it is never 1?

Comment: @CarlosFrostte That´s it. $\checkmark$

Comment: I was asked to graph the probability functions of discrete random variables that are distributed geometrically. What I do?

Comment: The pdf of a geometric function is $f_X(x)=p\cdot (1-p)^{x-1}$. For $p=0.5$ it  is $f_X(x)=0.5\cdot (0.5)^{x-1}$. The first values are $x=1,y=0.5; x=2,y=0.5^2; x=3,y=0.5^3,...$ I think you can graph this points.

Comment: I did, but I thought maybe I could do something else. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. One note:  $n\to \infty 1-0.5^n=1$. So it $is \ equal$ to $1$

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula -

$S_n = \frac{a(r^n - 1)}{r - 1}$

Where $S_n = 1$ and a is first term.